# Issue migrating Jenkins boolean pipeline to Teamcity build chain

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, teamcity, pipeline, continuous-deployment

I'm currently in the process of migrating several dozen Jenkins Pipelines over to TeamCity and I'm just learning TeamCity. Currently we have a large Jenkins pipeline containing 70+ build steps. In Jenkins, this pipeline can be built depending on a boolean check box for each step so we can choose what steps we wish to build.

For example, I want to run build steps 1, 17, 18, 22, 45, 60. And only those steps. We cant for example choose to run 17, 22, 18, 1, 60, 45. It must be sequential, but that's okay.

In TeamCity, I've been reading up on build chains but this seems to be an everything or nothing choice. So my question is, is there equivalent functionality in TeamCity that allows us to manually run a sequence of chosen builds? Not manually run single builds individually.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long while tinkering, I found my solution. In the case of Jenkins, a .groovy script is run. In TeamCity, I had to add a configuration parameter and click "edit" under the Spec: label. Choosing a checkbox allows me to create a pipeline similar to Jenkins. I can add as many parameters as I like.

I then create a Build Step with the Runner Type set to "Command Line". I can then run a bash script on my agent. An example being:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ %01. Configure% == true ]]; then
    ./config_environ.sh %00. Environment%
fi

if [[ %02. Build Kernel% == true ]]; then
    ./build_kernel.sh
fi
```

To run this 'pipeline', I click the three dots next to Run (Run custom build), navigate to the parameters tab, and select the build configuration I need. The UI isn't as nice as Jenkins, but it suits my needs.

Attached is the final output. Hopefully this helps others in the future.

[image]